# Modal filtering with Vandermonde matrix - Artificial viscosity

Tags: computational-physics, viscosity, shock-waves

I am trying to implement a 2D shock detector for an artificial viscosity model to control strong nonlinearities in compressible fluids. The method I am relying on is originally from:

Yu, M. L., Giraldo, F. X., Peng, M., & Wang, Z. J. (2015). Localized artificial viscosity stabilization of discontinuous Galerkin methods for nonhydrostatic mesoscale atmospheric modeling. Monthly Weather Review, 143(12), 4823-4845.

The main step of this technique, in eq. 22 of the previously cited paper, is to compute the higher-order modal coefficients $\hat{\mathbf{U}}$ of a field $\mathbf{U}$ of order $p$ over a given mesh element. In my case, I use a Gauss-Lobatto-Legendre nodal distribution. To perform the nodal-to-modal transformation, i.e. to compute the modal coefficients from the nodal values in an element, I compute the Vandermonde matrix $\mathcal{V}$ and its inverse $\mathcal{V}^{-1}$. Then I extract the modal coefficients following:
$
\hat{\mathbf{U}} = \mathcal{V}^{-1}\mathbf{U}.
$
Each component of $\hat{\mathbf{U}}$ corresponds to a specific mode.

To finally perform the filtering, or mode reduction, and go back to the nodal domain, one performs
$
{\mathbf{U}}_{filt} = \mathcal{V}\mathcal{\Lambda}\mathcal{V}^{-1}\mathbf{U},
$
where $\mathcal{\Lambda}$ is a diagonal filtering matrix.

**My question is: In 2D, how should I choose the components of the matrix $\Lambda$ in order to extract a field ${\mathbf{U}}_{filt}$ of polynomial order $m$ from an initial field $U$ of polynomial order $p > m$ ?**

I ask this question because I wonder how the various modal coefficients are distributed in the vector $\hat{\mathbf{U}}$ when on computes $\hat{\mathbf{U}} = \mathcal{V}^{-1}\mathbf{U}$. Are the lower-order modes in the first components and the higher-order ones in the last components ?

**edit**: Following tpg2114's comment, my Vandermonde matrix for a 2d medium is built as follows:
$
\mathcal{V}_{ij} = J_{x}^{l(j)}(\mathbf{x}_i) J_{z}^{k(j)}(\mathbf{x}_i),
$
where $J$ is the Jacobi polynomial either along x or z, $\mathbf{x}_i$ is the location of the $i^{th}$ node in the element and $n,m$ are the mapping between the matrix index  and the polynomial order in a given direction such that: along $z$, $k(j) = modulo(j-1,N)$ where $N$ is the number of nodes along one direction and along $x$, $l(j) = (j-1)//N$ where $//$ is the integer division, i.e. the quotient.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried writing out the matrix and multiplication for a simple system? For example, 2nd or 3rd order in 1d for a single element? I suspect it will just depend on how you order your polynomial coefficients and so it's an implementation choice more than a universal rule

Comment: You are right, I was hoping someone could have  had already written down the equations. In my case, I compute the Vandermonde matrix such that: $ \mathcal{V}_{ij} = J_x^{n(j)}(\mathbf{x}_i) J_z^{m(j)}(\mathbf{x}_i) $, where $J$ is the Jacobi polynomial either along x or z, $\mathbf{x}_i$ is the location of the $i^{th}$ node in the element and $n, m$ are the mapping between the matrix index $j$ and the polynomial order in a given direction such that: $m(j) = modulo(j,N)$ where $N$ is the number of nodes along one direction.